# Sketching the surface $x^2+y^2+4z^2 = 1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, solid-geometry

> Let the surface $S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ be the solutions of the equation $g(x, y, z)$ $ = 1$ where $g(x,y,z)=x^2 +y^2 +4z^2$. Let $U$ be the finite region of S satisfying $z > 0$ and let $C$ be the boundary of $U$. Sketch the surface $S$, the region $U$ and boundary $C$.

So I've trouble visualising this. I know I've to sketch $x^2+y^2+4z^2 = 1$, so I thought I should let $y=0$. Then $x^2+4z^2 = 1$ is an ellipse, which I can draw. Similarly, $y^2+4z^2 = 1$ is an ellipse. Letting $z = 0$ then $x^2+y^2 = 1$a circle of radius $1$. However, I'm unable to put this together in 3-D.

Also, what's the definition of boundary? The set of inequalities that bound that part of the surface?

EDIT: If sketch all three in 3D axis, I get this:

[image]

The two ellipses are inside the circle, which is wrong.

EDIT 2:

[image]

EDIT 3: Should it look like this?

[image]

But in that case I would like to ask what happened to the circle in the $xy$ plane?

Comment: Your approach is correct. Are you drawing the ellipses and circle in three separate plane diagrams or are you drawing them in a 3D coordinate system? The former method may not help but the latter should make it clear.

Comment: For visualization, setting each variable to zero can be helpful, but really just take level curves. For example, $z=0$, $z=1/2$, and $z=1$. Then you should see it more easily. In some sense, there are going to be a bunch of circles with decreasing radius. It's going to look like a symmetric egg (more formally called an ellipsoid.)

Comment: If you stretch the $z$ coordinate ($z'=2z$), you get a sphere...

Comment: Identify the set of $z$ for which equation is valid. For instance, what happens if $z=1$? For each valid $z$, look at the reduced equation. Here, you would get circle in $xy$-plane for each valid $z$. Then lift the circle upwards to the height $z$, if $z > 0$. otherwise downwards.

Comment: @JohnDouma I guess my trouble comes from trying to draw them in 3D coordinate system. If I transfer the 2D graphs to 3D coordinates, what should I do to them in between? If transfer them straight into 3D coordinates, I get the sketch I've put in the OP.

Comment: Use your flat drawings like an engineer or architect. Label the $xy$ plane the top view, the $yz$ plane the front view and the $xz$ plane the side view. That should work.

Comment: Also, in each view label the intercepts so the scale works. The shape should look something like a lens.

Comment: @JohnDouma Thanks. I've updated my attempt at drawing it based on your tips. Am I getting any close? I think the biggest obstacle for me is the fact that the circle we get when considering slices is bigger than the ellipses, so in terms of intuition it beats me how we end up with an ellipsoid. Also I'm confused by the idea of a boundary - what is it in this context?

Comment: Another way to see that this is an ellipsoid which looks kind of like a Junior Mint is to notice that $x^2+y^2+4z^2=r^2+4z^2$ in cylindrical coordinates. This means that the curve is the same ellipse in the $rz$ plane for any angle $\theta$. Therefore, it is like taking an ellipse in the $yz$ plane and rotating that $360$ degrees around the $z$ axis.